# What's this number near my flags?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

Sorry if this has been mentioned before, but I was not able to figure it out researching around Meta. But my flagging history has numbers near it:

[image: lol]

*Does not represent actual flagging history. Names of the questions and usernames are replaced with JavaScript to protect the original authors.*

I see "2" and "1"s. What are they representing?

Comment: Those are number of answers each question has. Rule: when in doubt, mouse hover :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's this number near my flags? I see "2" and "1"s. What are they representing?

**Number displayed on the right side of the post title is the count of answers posted on the flagged question.**

Reference: [What does the little number following “closed” signify in flag history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140149/what-does-the-little-number-following-closed-signify-in-flag-history)

Answer (score 7):

The numbers represent different statistics of the post.

- **Left** :  number of votes
- **Right** :  number of answers

This information is displayed in the tooltip for these numbers:

[image]